# vb.net error on something

Tags: vb.net, runtime-error

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Shell("CMD.exe")
        SendKeys.Send("net user")("TextBox1.Text")("TextBox2.Text")
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
    End Sub
End Class
```

It says:

> Error 1 Expression is not an array or a method, and cannot have an
>   argument list.

for SendKeys.Send("net user")

Comment: i found out how to fix it its working now

Answer (score 0):

Glad that you have resolved, but trust me, this is not the correct way to work with CMD.exe from inside a NET app.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim pi = new ProcessStartInfo()
    pi.FileName = "CMD.EXE"
    pi.Arguments = "/K NET USER " + textBox1.Text + " " + TextBox2.Text
    Process.Start(pi)
End Sub
```

[ProcessStartInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx)
[Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)